# Modify sms.db for iPhone (iOS 6+)

Tags: ios, iphone, database, sms

Recently I've been working on importing my sms.db from my old iPhone 3GS to another old iPhone (this time a 4S) as part of a challenge I set myself.

Now that I've achieved that, I wanted to modify the database and have the changes reflected in the SMS application on the iPhone 4S.

So far I've used BackupTrans SMS transfer to copy the SMS information from the 3GS to the 4S and I'm using SQLiteStudio to edit the database, however, whenever I commit the changes the "modified" message disappears from the log history in the SMS app on the 4S.

I'm aware that the sms.db-shm & sms.db-wal have some form of connection with the sms.db file, but I can't figure out how to get those files to update correctly to reflect the changes in the sms.db file.

My computer system is a Windows 7 OS, but I do have access to a OSX installation should it prove necessary to need one.

Any thoughts you might have on this issue are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it!.

I found what was causing the files not to update, it was a permissions error on the file.

For those that wish to try it themselves;

- You need to download iFile (from Cydia)
- Place the sms.db file back in the phone in "/private/var/mobile/library/sms/sms.db"
- Open iFile, and navigate to the same directory on the iPhone.
- Go to Permissions and change Owner from "root" to "mobile"
- Close iFile
- Restart the iPhone (Normal Shutdown or Force Reset will work)
- Wait for iPhone to boot back up and then enter the SMS App

Hope this helps any other budding tweakers.

Comment: thank you, u just saved me hours upon hours of work :)